# Is it possible to implement such a database structure in springboot？

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use hibernate as the framework for springboot CUBA operations. But I have a problem, our workout information and recipe information are coming from external API. This means that I only need to store the recipe and workout ids in the database. The database structure is as follows.
[DB sturucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxApo.png)

As the data is provided by the API, we have not created corresponding entity tables for workouts and recipes. But then the problem arises. What should be done with the join table in this case. I mean the premise of @manytomany is that two entity tables are needed, and we only have entity tables for users. Even if we use a joint primary key, there is still a need to add user_id as a foreign key in the joint primary key. How can we mark user_id as a foreign key without a workout or recipe entity table?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing but I'll try to provide an answer for what I understood.

If the data is completely external, you can map an element collection consisting of ids only:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  // other fields
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "recipse_user")
  Set<Long> recipeIds;
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "workout_user")
  Set<Long> workoutIds;
}
```